# find() STL Algorithm... What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, string, vector

At the current moment, I'm trying to get the basics of C++ down so learning to use the find() Algorithm is where I'm at. When I use find() within my code, I am having problems when what I'm looking has more than one word (ex: when I look for FIFA I get the results I'm looking for. But when I look for Ace Combat, I get an Invalid game output). If anyone can shed any light on what I'm doing wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
//Games List
//Make a list of games I like and allow for user select one of the games

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string>::const_iterator iter;

    vector<string> games;
    games.push_back("FIFA");
    games.push_back("Super Mario Bros.");
    games.push_back("Ace Combat");
    games.push_back("Sonic");
    games.push_back("Madden");

    cout << "These are my some of my favorite game titles.\n";
    for (iter = games.begin(); iter != games.end(); ++iter)
    cout << *iter << endl;

    cout << "\nSelect one of these games titles.\n";
    string game;
    cin >> game;    
    iter = find(games.begin(), games.end(), game);
    if (iter != games.end())
        cout << game << endl;
    else
        cout << "\nInvalid game.\n"; 
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is at cin.

like 
cin >> game;

if you input "Ace Combat", game == "Ace".

it would stop at first blank.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `cin >> game;` statement reads only one word of the input. So when a user enters "Ace Combat", your program reads and searches for "Ace". To solve the problem, use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read the whole line and not a single word. For example, replace `cin >> game;` with `std::getline(cin, game);`.

Comment: Fairly new to programming so gonna have to look into 'std::getline()'. Book I'm reading basically set me up for failure on this one but thanks!

Comment: Where std::getline() answer the question, it is not a free lunch in my opinion. With the original code superfluous spaces were ignored. Now suddenly they matter. So, if you type "FIFA " followed by CR, it no longer matches.

Comment: @user515430: `cin` is in text mode and it removes `\r` in Windows. But  you have the point — extra spaces, for examples, won't be removed.

Comment: looking back on previous chapters I realize the author would do things like AceCombat to avoid this type of problem. I don't recall a warning on spaces in between words but maybe I looked past it. Thanks a lot for the help.